# Highcharts Export Service Gantt Chart not working

Tags: node.js, highcharts, gantt-chart

Attempting to pilot a server-side render of a gantt chart using **highcharts-export-server**, but unable to get the series data to render at all.

As per [the docs](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md), I've tried running the export [via commandline](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md#running) and [as a node module](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md#using-as-a-nodejs-module), but I always get an empty graph with the title, subtitle and series name displaying, but none of the actual data.

[Failed Gantt Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o1SQ.png)

All the basic line graph example configurations work and I'm able to render the chart using the `Highcharts.ganttChart` method via the browser, so I believe it's specific to the Gantt chart configuration for the export server, or related to the millisecond date conversion (as you can see in the screenshot, the X Axis is not rendering as dates, but rather plain numbers). As per suggestions on other threads, I ran `build.js` in the `node_modules/highcharts-export-server`, globally for the commandline attempt and project-locally for the node module attempt, making sure to enable the both the *gantt* and *moment* libraries, but that didn't help either.

Including my options json below. I haven't been able to find a gantt config example specifically for the export server, so this is my best attempt to interpolate what they'd be:

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Gantt PoC"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "Timeline"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Gantt Demo",
      "type": "gantt",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "Demo Task 1",
          "id": "demo_task_1",
          "start": 1564113600000,
          "end": 1564718400000
        },
        {
          "name": "Demo Task 2",
          "id": "demo_task_2",
          "start": 1564113600000,
          "end": 1564718400000
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 1563681600000,
    "max": 1571803200000
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything obviously wrong with my config, if I missed any crucial steps to prep the environment, or any ideas you may have for me to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, upon installing node export server you get to choose to include Gantt module. You need it in order to export Gantt charts. Secondly, you need to use a correct constructor. In case of Gantt charts it is ganttChart. Try to use following command: highcharts-export-server --infile gantt.json --outfile gantt.png --type png --constr ganttChart, where gantt.json is a correct JSON file with options for required chart.

Comment: @pawel_d Thanks for the reply! So, definitely made sure to add the gantt library during the install. For the `--constr` arg, I had seen that, on the docs it specifically stated it was only for 'Chart' or 'StockChart', but will definitely give that a shot.

Also, would you happen to have an example for the gantt.json, or verify that the one included in my post is accurate? I have searched high and low and can't find any specific reference for the gantt config used for the export flow.

Comment: When it comes to gantt.json file, here is a simplest example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gk96b41f/ from which you can get options object and use it as a JSON to generate a simplest Gantt chart. As for your JSON object, it's of course correct too (I was able to generate a correct image using it).

Answer (score 0):

i also tried to generate image using ganttchart, just i tried constructor which you suggested working perfectly, Thanks.

```
highcharts-export-server --infile gantt.json --outfile gantt.png --type png --constr ganttChart
```

actually i tried with `HTTP Server` as well, working perfectly. Thanks @[pawel_d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6368761/pawel-d)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const chartExporter = require('highcharts-export-server');
chartExporter.initPool();
const chartDetails = {
  type: "png",
  constr : 'ganttChart',
  options: {
    series: [{
      data: [{
        start: 1,
        end: 10
      }]
    }]
  }
};
chartExporter.export(chartDetails, (err, res) => {
  // Get the image data (base64)
  let imageb64 = res.data;
  // Filename of the output
  let outputFile = "bar.png";
  // Save the image to file
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, imageb64, "base64", function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  console.log("Saved image!");
  chartExporter.killPool();
});
```